# how to read gdx from gams with multiple tables in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a gdx with several tables and I need to convert them into dataframes in python but I can't even read the gdx.

I used:

```
import gdx
f = gdx.File('resultados.gdx', lazy=True, implicit=True, skip={})
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Comment: The error you're encountering indicates that the file path you provided to the gdx.File() function is None or empty. The NoneType error occurs when a variable that should contain an object or value is instead assigned None.

Comment: How could the route be added? I have tried to put it inside file() but it keeps giving me an error. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

```
from gdxpds import GdxFile

# Replace 'path/to/your/resultados.gdx' with the actual path to your GDX file.
file_path = 'path/to/your/resultados.gdx'

# You need to open the GDX file
gdx_file = GdxFile(file_path)

# Then try to get the list of symbols (tables) in the GDX file
symbols = gdx_file.get_symbols()

# Create a dictionary to store the DataFrames
dataframes = {}

# Convert each symbol to a DataFrame and store it in the dictionary
for symbol in symbols:
    dataframes[symbol] = gdx_file.to_dataframe(symbol)
```